# If I casted an int member of a struct to char* to serialize it, should I cast it as int* type when deserializing it?

Tags: c++, pointers, deserialization

The struct date has two `int` types on which the write function of the struct uses `reinterpret_cast<char*>()` to store it on disk. To read it back again from disk and to store it as an `int` variable of the struct, should I not `reinterpret_cast` the `int day` variable as `<int*>` to properly store it?
Like so:

```
os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&day),sizeof(day)); //to cast it into char* to store it in file
```

and, to deserialize it like so:

```
is.read(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&day),sizeof(day)); //to cast it into char* to read it from file
```

instead of:

```
is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&day),sizeof(day)); //which just converts it back to char* to read from file
```

The reason is that I want to be able to perform arithmetic on `int day`.

Here's my code:

```
struct date{
    int day;
    string month;
    int year;

    void read(istream &is) // to deserialize date and read it from disk
    {
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&day), sizeof(day));
        size_t size;
        if (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size)))
        {
            month.resize(size);
            is.read(&month[0], size);
        }
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&year), sizeof(year));
    }

    void write(ostream &os) const //to serialize struct date
    {
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&day), sizeof(day));
        size_t size = month.size();
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));
        os.write(month.c_str(), size);
        os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&year), sizeof(year));
    }
};
```

Comment: The code you show looks OK to me. I'm not sure I quite understand the question.

Comment: You can't just `reinterpret_cast` to an `int` like that, this would be undefined behavior. Why don't you just `is >> day`. Your stream would need to be opened in binary mode.

Comment: yeah the code is right. i am trying to serialize the `struct date` and write it to a file in the disk, so to serialize it, considering in mind on most machines the size of `char` is 1 byte in c++, i am converting the `int day` member of the `struct date` to `char` type. that is great to store it on the disk, but when reading the serialized struct back from disk to a `struct date` variable and to store it, i want to use the `int day` member that i read from disk as an `int type` to perform arithmetic on it like '++int' so i am looking to see if i can deserialize it as `int type`

Comment: @J.Schultke im thinking the same. but don't `int` types differ in size from machine to machine?

Comment: @J.Schultke "Binary mode" just means "don't perform end-of-line translation between OS-native format and `\n`". Whether in text or binary mode, `is >> day` reads text and attempts to parse it as a decimal representation of an integer. And yes, you can too cast an address of an object to `char*` in order to access that object's memory representation.

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma Your code does deserialize an `int` type just fine. What specific problem do you have with it? Are you not getting back the same values you've written? I fail to grasp the nature of the difficulty.

Comment: in the function `void read(istream& is)` when i say `is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&day),sizeof(day));` does the `reinterpret_cast<char*>` doesn't mean whatever is read from file on the disk treat it as `char` type instead of `int` type until the `sizeof(day)`

Comment: so if `day` is read and treated like a `char` type instead of `int` type how can i perform `int` arithmetic on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, as it is, and there is no cause to worry about `day` (or `year`) being interpreted as anything other than the `int` that is declared to be.

In the calls to `is.read` and `os.write`, the only thing you are casting (to a `char*` pointer) is the passed **address** of the `day` variable. This, together with the following argument (`sizeof(day)`) tells those calls to read/write the appropriate number of bytes (a `char` is always *one byte*, and the `sizeof` operator gives the size in *bytes*) into/from the given address.

So, if (as is quite common), an `int` is 4 bytes on your compiler/platform, then 4 characters will be read from the stream and placed at the address given - the four 'component' bytes of the integer will be placed into to the memory assigned for that integer.

The cast to `char *` is required because the STL defines that the `read()` and `write()` functions take such a pointer. This is because the streams are implemented on a character-by-character basis; thus, to read any other type of variable, you need to cast its address, and provide the relevant size of that type.

Comment: great. it makes sense now. you are saying that instead of treating the variable `int day` as a character, the `reinterpret_cast` of `read/write` functions treats the `byte information` of the `int day` as `char` or a character sequence and stores them on the disk?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma In a way, yes. You are simply passing the address of a piece of memory, plus the number of bytes to read/write. Casting the pointer type is required to conform with the functions' prototypes, and is safe here, because the 'source' pointer is the (safely-derived) address of the data.

Comment: one last question, do you think i should use the `reinterpret_cast` here or is there a better `cast` to use?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma That's about the best you can use. The only other option would be the 'evil' C-style cast: `(char*)(&day)` - which is worse, IMHO.